# Laravel 4 Commands stopped working suddenly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Back from vacation, and when I'm trying to run one of my previously working command:

`php artisan list`

Throws me:

`[root@api2]# php artisan list
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to a member function getArgument() on a non-object","file":"\/var\/www\/html\/api2.alariscms.com\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Console\/Command.php","line":153}}`

And I seriously cannot understand why this happens. I tried debugging the file that throws an error. It awaits argument:
`InputInterface $input` but it gets `NULL`

I don't know what can go wrong on a framework level to stop receiving the required object.

Any ideas where to start debugging from? Or I can reload configurations / update laravel via cmd?

Thanks

Comment: you could try a `composer update` perhaps Laravel got corrupted.  Not sure how, though

Comment: It appears it was dying somewhere where I was using $this->argument('name').. not sure how it got clogged like that, because I wasn't even requesting the command itself, just the list or dump.

Comment: Is there no stack trace of the exception? Also, command's constructor should not execute the command's logic, but the `handle` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
php artisan dump
composer dump-autoload
check for current Laravel version
```

and then go to that specific command and check for bug there.

Also, what kind of argument are you trying to pass to command ? Is that object - if so check where is implementation of that class ?

Comment: [root@api2]# php artisan dump
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to a member function getArgument() on a non-object","file":"\/var\/www\/html\/api2.alariscms.com\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Console\/Command.php","line":153}}{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to a member function getArgument() on a non-object","file":"\/var\/www\/html\/api2.alariscms.com\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Console\/Command.php","line":153}}